# How to show that 0.5Y is an unbiased estimator of alpha?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation

How do I show that 0.5Y in part (a) down below is an unbiased estimator of alpha? If n, the number of observations, is very large then Y would equal to alpha+alpha=2*alpha an then 0.5Y=alpha so E(0.5Y)=E(alpha)=alpha but the size of n is not stated so how is this question supposed to be solved?
[image]

Comment: Do not [repost](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3826222/321264).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I show that 0.5Y in part (a) down below is an unbiased estimator of alpha?

The rv $Y\cdot n$ is evidently a binomial

$$nY\sim Bin(n;2\alpha)$$

thus

$$\mathbb{E}[nY]=2n\alpha$$

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=2\alpha$$

and evidently,

$$\mathbb{E}[\frac{Y}{2}]=\alpha$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability that a given observation is nonzero is $\alpha+\alpha$ so

$$\mathbb E\left(\frac{1}{2}Y\right)=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb E(Y)=\frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\alpha)=\alpha$$

Similarly

$$\mathbb E\left(\frac{1}{3}\overline{X}\right)=\frac{1}{3}\mathbb E\left(\overline X\right)=\frac{1}{3}\left(\alpha+2\alpha\right)=\alpha$$

Can you go from here to show that $\frac{1}{2}Y$ is more efficient? Since they're both unbiased estimators, you just need to determine which estimator has a smaller variance.

Comment: Thank you for your invaluable help! One thing, when you substitute alpha + alpha for Y, then are you assuming that n is very large? Because if the number of observations was very small, like 3, then it's not necessarily true that the proportion of nonzero observations is 2*alpha, since the sample is so small...

Comment: The expected value would still be $2\alpha$ regardless of the sample size. Consider flipping a coin $3$ times and letting $X$ denote the number of heads. Then $\mathbb E(X)=1.5$ but we'd never observe $1.5$ heads. The expected value can just be thought of as the arithmetic mean of a large number of realizations of your random variable.

Comment: That makes sense, yes. Thank you for clearing this up for me.

Comment: By the way, do you know if there's any other way to find the variance of 0.5Y than using the formula Var(X)=np(1-p) when we have nY follows Bin(n, 2*alpha)?